# Simplify the following complex fraction:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{9/x^2}{\large\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{x^2}{15}}$$

I have attempted to solve this problem a multitude of times and each time I get a different answer. Is it $\frac{360}{x^2}$, $\frac{360}{x^4}$, or as my calculator says $\frac{675}{8x^4}$? Please show the work as well so I understand how it is done. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean "complicated" fraction. When you say "complex" it might be interpeted as using complex numbers.

Comment: It says complex fraction on my worksheet

Comment: @DarthGeek: I've seen the term "complex" used to describe a fraction which contains fractions within its numerator or denominator. I agree with you, this wouldn't be my first choice of terminology, but it's out there, I'm afraid. "Compound" is also used, and seems better.

Comment: "Compound" seems to be the most appropriate choice IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First recall that
\[ \frac{a}{b} \pm \frac{c}{d} =\frac{ad \pm cb}{bd} \]
And 
\[ \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} =\frac{ad}{bc} \]
Then
\[
\frac{\frac{9}{x^{2}}}{\frac{x^{2}}{25}+\frac{x^{2}}{15}}= \frac{\frac{9}{x^{2}}}{\frac{15x^{2}+25x^{2}}{25\cdot 15}}= \frac{\frac{9}{x^{2}}}{\frac{40x^{2}}{375}}=\frac{9\cdot 375}{40x^{4}}= \frac{675}{8x^{4}}
\]

Answer (score 7):

Note: answer changed to reflect altered problem statement.
$$
  \frac{\frac{9}{x^2}}{\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{x^2}{15}}
    = \frac{\frac{9}{x^2}}{\frac{(15+25)x^2}{15\cdot 25}} 
    = \frac{9}{x^2\frac{40x^2}{375}} 
    = \frac{375\cdot 9}{40x^4} 
    = \frac{675}{8x^4}.
$$

Comment: So no x^4 in the denominator like my ti-89 says?

Comment: Doesn't look that way, assuming you entered the expression correctly above.

Comment: I fixed it up top-my apologies

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{9/x^2}{\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{x^2}{15}}=\frac{9/x^2}{\frac{3x^2+5x^2}{75}}=\frac{75*9}{8*x^2*x^2}=\frac{675}{8x^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\frac{9}{x^{2}}}{\frac{x^{2}}{25}+\frac{x^{2}}{15}}=\frac{\frac{9}{x^{2}}}{\frac{x^{2}}{25}+\frac{x^{2}}{15}}\times\frac{75x^{2}}{75x^{2}}=\frac{675}{8x^{4}}$$